# React-router. Missing router as context in component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use react-router v4 and i would like to programatically navigate to other url (i often need this in my stores). In react-router v3 it was so easy: u have only to use browserHistory.push(). But this time it's complicated. I can't use  as pointed [here](https://react-router.now.sh/auth-workflow) out of any react component. So, i try to get router from context. Here is my component

```js
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer, Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss, Link } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import Main_Store from '../main.store';
import Signin from '../../auth/components/signin.component';
import Signup from '../../auth/components/signup.component';
import Header from './header/header.component';
import Zone from '../../zone/components/zone.component';

const main_store = new Main_Store();

@observer
class Base extends Component {
   render() {
      const get_base = (props) => {
         return (
            <Provider main_store={main_store} profile={main_store.profile}>
               <div>
                  <Header main_store={main_store} />
                  <main>
                     <Match pattern={'/*/zone-**'} component={Zone} />
                     <Match pattern={'/*/signin'} component={Signin} />
                     <Match pattern={'/*/signup'} component={Signup} />
                  </main>
               </div>
            </Provider>
         )
      };
      return (
         <BrowserRouter>
            <Match pattern="/:view_type" render={(props) => get_base(props)} />
         </BrowserRouter>
      );
   }
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
}

Base.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default Base;
```

and my zone component which also want to have access to router

```js
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss, Link } from 'react-router';

@observer(['main_store'])
class Zone extends Component {
   render() {
      const { main_store } = this.props;
      return (
         <div>
            Zone component
         </div>
      );
   }
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      console.log('this Zone', this)
   }
}

Zone.contextTypes = {
   router: React.PropTypes.object,
   history: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default Zone;
```

but there is nothing. Router is undefined. What did i do wrong? Any other ideas how to programmatically navigate out of component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to access `context.router` through children of your `<BrowserRouter>` component. Because `<Base>` is a parent of your `<BrowserRouter>`, you cannot access `context.router` through it. If you move your `<BrowserRouter>` up a level (outside of the `<Base>`), your code should work.

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Base />
  </BrowserRouter>
), holder)
```

Comment: Thanks! that's works. By the way i have same context realization for child component (<Zone />) but it doesn't work. Perhaps it's because of HOC wrapper which inject props. But i hope i can try to inject router into app store and then spread it to any inner component

Comment: I would have to see the code for your `<Zone>` component to say anything with certainty, but an HOC shouldn't be breaking the context. Likewise hopefully React Router v4 will be adding a `withRouter` HOC that will allow you to just wrap components that need access to the `router` and you won't have to mess around with the `context` yourself.

Comment: Thanks Paul for ur help.  I have added code for Zone component in my question.

Comment: Typically you should start a new question instead of adding on to an existing one. Regarding your `<Zone>` component, are you saying that when you log in `cDM`, `this.context.router` is undefined?

Comment: I didn't know this. Yes, `this.context.router` is undefined but parent component (<Base />) have it though.

Comment: If you remove the `@observer` decorator from the `<Zone>` component, does it receive the `context.router`?

Comment: yes. So, u have found solution for this problem. Thanks! I'll try to provide this router through Provider